# Trigger an event when a div is populated/visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom, addeventlistener

I want to trigger an event once a DIV is populated from the back, 2 nodes are inserted in my DIV. I'm using this:

```
$(function () {
    var xml = document.querySelector('#XML');

    xml.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (ev) {  
        doSomething();
    }, false);
});
```

This works when the XML div is populated once the doc is loaded or reloaded. 
At some point, the user clicks a button and the div#XML is populated dynamically without a reload and even though a DOM node is inserted into my element, nothing happens.

How can I trigger "doSomething()" when my div changes?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine. Like you can see in [Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) and the relative compatibility [HERE](http://help.dottoro.com/ljfvvdnm.php#additionalEvents):

```js
$(function () {
  $('#XML').on("DOMNodeInserted", function (ev) {
    console.log('DO SOMETHING');
  });

  $('#btnAdd').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#XML').append($('<p>', {text: 'this is a new paragragh'}));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div id="XML"></div>

<button id="btnAdd">Add a paragragh to div</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code might be the one you looking for. It will look for changes in your `div` every `1000 milliseconds`, you can change that according to your requirements. If your div has some `text` initially then update the `oldVal` accordingly.

```
$('#XML').change(function(){
   alert("div has changed!");
   // replace with your actions
});

var oldVal = "";
function InputChangeListener()
{
   if($('#XML').val() != oldVal)
   {
     oldVal  = $('#XML').val();
     $('#XML').change();    
   }
}
setInterval(InputChangeListener, 1000);
```